# Twilio Voice Mail On Live Call

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm trying to build a power/progressive dialer for twilio.  What I want to happen is that if a call is made and a voice mail message is heard then I want to give the sales agent an option of leaving a pre-recorded voice message.

It's pretty easy to redirect the call and use the the  verb to play the pre recorded message.  Unfortunately this plays the message straight away and therefore the agent has to wait until the end of the voice message to press the "leave voice mail" option.

Any idea how I could let the agent hangup and the voice message be left automatically after the beep is detected.  Twilio has AMD detection but only on the  verb not on the redirect.  One option might be to start another call at the same time and therefore the number would be busy and a message could be left straight away, but this seems like to much of a hack, prone to error and would show two missed calls.

Answer (score 0):

It is an experimental feature, however, you could attempt to use [Answering Machine Detection](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#handling-outcomes-answering-machines)'s parameter `ifMachine` whereby Twilio will inform you in its TwiML request whether `AnsweredBy` parameter is set to `human` or `machine`.

`ifMachine` has two possible values:

- `Continue` If Twilio detects an answering machine, it will wait
  until it hears a beep before continuing with the call flow.
- `Hangup` If Twilio detects an answering machine, it will hangup
  immediately.

This feature is not normally recommended due to its experimental nature and could  falsely detect a human. However, theoretically your sales agent already knows they reached the machine, so you can try to use this feature to detect the "beep" after `machine` is detected and then redirect the call flow to your pre-recorded voice message.

**March 2017 Update**:

[Answering Machine Detection](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/answering-machine-detection) has been update.

For example, the `MachineDetection` parameter can be `Enable` or `DetectMessageEnd`. `Enable` returns results as soon as recognition is complete. `DetectMessageEnd` will wait until after a greeting to return results if an answering machine is detected.

Using new AMD would look like this:

```
curl 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX123456789/Calls.json' -X POST \
--data-urlencode 'To=+1562300000' \
--data-urlencode 'From=+18180000000' \
--data-urlencode 'MachineDetection=Enable' \
--data-urlencode 'Url=https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/EH8ccdbd7f0b8fe34357da8ce87ebe5a16' \
-u ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX123456789:[AuthToken]
```

Comment: Unfortunately AMD doesn't work once the call is in progress. A connects to B.  A hears B's voice mail box. A wants to leave voice message but has to wait until the end of the message to redirect the call to a <Play> verb.  A wants to leave the voice message without having to wait until the end of B's voice mail box message.

Comment: Ah makes sense. I had never tried before as yours seems to be a fairly unique ask I was hoping it would offer a workaround there. Sorry!